# find-library equivalent for C internal source code files

Tags: files

Is there a built-in Emacs equivalent of `find-library` for the C internal source code files?

If there is an additional step needed to create an index of the files (e.g., `make tags`) when building Emacs, please include that step in the answer.

In a nutshell, I'd like to type `M-x find-src-library` and type the letters `fri` and hit the `tab` key and have it complete to `fringe.c` and then open that file when I press the enter key.

Comment: I don't think there is a built-in function for this, perhaps because not everyone has a source installation of Emacs, or because different builds use different source files, but it should be fairly simple to write a custom function using any one of or a combinaton of the variables `build-files` and `source-directory`, the functions `directory-files` and `directory-files-recursively`, and the new functionality provided by the `progmodes/project.el` API.